# Style not applied for element with filter in angular in edge browser

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, microsoft-edge, ng-style

I have a scenario that i will be changing the text element color based on the color which user chooses.

Here is my code.

```
<i ng-style="{'color':MyObj.Color}" class="icon-Icon_Store_SMS"></i>&nbsp;
<span ng-style="{'color':MyObj.Color}" ng-if="contactNo.length > 0">{{contactNo | telephoneFilter }}</span>
<span ng-style="{'color':MyObj.Color}" ng-if="contactNo.length == 0">{{'8888888888' | telephoneFilter }}</span>
```

In the above set of statements, i will be changing phone number color to the one which user chooses and the code was working fine in all browsers(IE too) except edge. In Edge browser, color applied for the icon but not for the 2 span elements. When i checked for the cause, i found that removing telephoneFilter code was working fine. TelephoneFilter is angular custom filter which customizes phone number display say something like (123)45678901.

Can anyone guide me how to overcome this issue/any solution

Thanks in advance,

Selva

Comment: Do you know how to mark right answers? 14 questions but not marked one right answer.

Comment: Yes, he can do.

Comment: I have accepted as answer for certain questions for which i get the correct/relative info.

Comment: @Selva, thats good. Could you create a fiddle or plnkr to reproduce your problem?

Comment: @lin When i checked some more detail i came to know that there was no connection with angular. The issue was purely browser based and it was due to hyphen in phone number . Say (123)092-1234 in which when i remove hyphen color gets applied otherwise not . This occurs only in edge browser . Find the plunker link. Try opening in all browsers and find the differences

https://plnkr.co/edit/l7pii93jcGBoEA1QIann?p=preview